# Confuse terms in Angular JS tutorial

Tags: angularjs, properties, naming

I'm following a tutorial and I have difficulties to understand a certain sentence which talks about the problem that can occur when naming my properties in Angular:

> It quietly tolerates all property access errors, including nested properties on nonexistent parents and out-of-bounds array access.
>
> aliasing variables as a way to cope with variable shadowing

My english is good enough to know what is written, but I really don't understand what is "nested properties on nonexistent parents" and "aliasing variables as a way to cope with variable shadowing". I did some research, but couldn't clearly understand.

Could someone give me a clear explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
obj : { 
    first: {
        second: [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

Trying to do this:

```
obj.nonexistent.prop // Nested property on nonexistent parent
obj.first.second[1000] // Out of bound array access
```

Would throw an error in javascript, but Angular doesn't throw an error

For aliasing variables as a way to cope with variable shadowing, imagine this:

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="outerCount = $index">
    {{outerCount + 1}}. {{item.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="item in item.items">
       {{outerCount + 1}}.{{$index + 1}}. {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From [here](http://www.angularjsbook.com/angular-basics/chapters/collections/)

In an ng-repeat, the `$index` variable changes to point at the current index of the loop each iteration. So if you have nested loops, you'll lose a reference to the outer `$index` variable. This is *variable shadowing*. To use the outer variable, you can use `ng-init` and set it to the `$index` outside. Now, you've **aliased** the outer `$index` variable to `outerCount`.

Hope this is clear!

Comment: Thanks, it's really clear now! But I just added one more thing in my question at the same time you seem to have answer my question.

Comment: @KévinDuguay I've edited the post to explain your second question.

Comment: Could you quickly explain what nested means? I'm not entirely sure that I understood that concept.

Comment: Suppose if you did `obj.nonexistent`. Javascript doesn't throw an error, but returns `undefined`. This is because no such property exists on obj. Now, if you try to do `obj.nonexistent.prop`, you've just tried accessing prop on an undefined object, which throws an error. The nested means accessing nonexistent ( a top level property) directly does not cause an error, but accessing a nested property (`nonexistent.prop`) causes it.

Comment: I think I got what you meant, but to be sure, here is what I got:

In your example, we have a loop inside an other one. Each loop have a property $index, but you wouldn't be able to access the one of the first loop inside the second loop, since this loop already use it. So putting the $index in a var with ng-init solve the problem.

So, variable shadowing is when a var is nested (like with $index inside the first loop) and if you loose reference to that loop, you can't use it anymore.